# Collapse content below toolbar with CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

Hello there I've been trying to use the code for collapsing toolbar in a slightly different way. Let me show you my layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabControl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabMaxWidth="500dp">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/headerContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/topLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tabContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Basically I want to collapse headerContainer keeping tabControl in place. However what really happens is that headerContainer is never collapsed and remains on top the along with the tabControl.

I have no idea why this does not work since when I put headerContainer above the tabControl the headerContainer is collapsed as it should be.

It's just that when I put it the headerContainer below tabControl the stuff is not collapsed anymore. 
I've tried the different solutions but none seem to work, the layout appears to be correct and it should be collapsed but it is not.

I've been struggling with this for two days now, so any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea why this does not work since when I put headerContainer
>   above the tabControl the headerContainer is collapsed as it should be.

You have set :

```
app:layout_collapseMode="none"
```

In `headerContainer` so, try  this (in `headerContainer` `FrameLayout`):

```
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
```

---

Also, couldn't see any `Toolbar`s in your `layout`. There was just a `TabLayout` in it.

Comment: I tried all of the possible collapseModes, and none made it collapse :(

Answer (score 0):

If I get your right you want to behavior in the screenshots, when scrolling vertically?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                app:tabMaxWidth="500dp"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Also set the toolbar in the activity: setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I do not want a toolbar in this screen, I just want the controls I have in the layout

Comment: and what do you want collapsible?

Comment: The content within CollapsibleToolbarLayout, in another words headerContainer